# Поиск всех модифицированных файлов

Tags: clearcase, контроль-версий, cleartool, консоль

Как с помощь cleartool можно найти имена всех измененных и добавленных файлов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переходим в папку со снапшотом (к примеру его имя BR0123). Далее в консоли выполняем

```
cleartool find . -branch brtype(BR0123) -print > output.txt
```

В итоге, в файле output.txt лежит список.